# Prestashop 1.6 - TAX Calculation - Explanation

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've got a problem on PS 1.6.0.9 after about one mounth of customizzazions I found out a problem in TAX calculations.

I have used the TAX calculations for Switzerland, with the lowest rate (2,5%).

There is something wrong in the calculation algorithm. (See the attached picture. Sorry, my backoffice is in italian)

Final price: 6.00
TAX: 2.5%
Price TAX excluded: 5.853659

The right price would be: 5.85

It's also wrong the TAX calculation in the shopping chart and the problem is getting bigger and bigger wth multiple items.

I tried all three approximation method offered by the system, but the result is everytime wrong...

Some hints on how to solve that problem?

[image: BackOffice ScreenShot]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is you code for the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal

6.00 include Tax so without tax is 6 - 2.5% of tax = 5.8536585.....

The calcul is

```
6 / 1.025 = 5.8536585[...]
```

Comment: Sure, but you agree that it is wrong?
It's much simple like that: 6-(6*0,025)
And it is right the result... The approzimation you mentioned when I buy more than one item is intolerable.

If you know the source of PS, do you know where to find the source of this calculation in order to change it?

Comment: Hi did you have look on official forum  ? https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/235504-tax-is-calculated-wrong-in-prestashop-it-has-to-be-not-just-me-but-everyone/?p=1160341

Comment: Yes, I have made many tries, at the end your reply was true and my considerations were wrong. The final price (P_f) is calculated on the price, tax excluded (P_te): P_f = P_te + (P_te * TAX). My consideration was: P_te = P_f - (P_f*TAX). But the right way is yours and the PrestaShop one: P_te = P_f - (P_te * TAX) --> P_te = P_f / (1+TAX).
Thank you for your reply and I am sorry with StackOverflow for this wrong topic. Ciao!